# Load PDF in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small C# application where I load a PDF into the Web browser control which I named `webBrowser`. When I load it, it starts in the Acrobat Reader witch was set as my default viewer.

The problem I have is that when I change the default viewer for my system, in the `webBrowser` the PDF will be still loaded with Acrobat Reader.

My code:

```
webBrowser_.Navigate(filePath);
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you restarted your system within these two days? If not, maybe try this.

Comment: I need something to work without restarting the system(if lets say this will fix the issue). @QualityCatalyst